# How to copy a database from one computer to another?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database in SQL Server 2008, which I want to copy to another computer.

How do I make such a copy?

Once this is done, what should I do at the other computer to build the database once again from my copy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simple Answer: Back it up, then restore it on the other computer.

Have a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966495.aspx

There's a lot of stuff there, but essentially, right click on the database, Tasks > Backup. Fill in the options to perform a full backup to somewhere.

Once it has created the backup (one big file, by convention with a BAK extension), on the second computer, right click the Databases folder, Restore Database and follow the prompts.

You can do it as well in SQL if you wish:

- Backup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx
- Restore: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

There might be times when it's better to detach and move, but this approach always feels a bit safer!

This will copy both structure and the data in the database.

Comment: And the backup and restore can be done while the DB is online which is nice

Comment: Sorry for the necropost : In order to restore in another server, you must provide a path to the target server. What path do you provide if the server is in another PC?

Answer (score 35):

Using SQL Server Management Studio, here are the steps:

1.Right-click the database and select **Tasks** | **Backup**

[image]

2.Make sure that the Backup type is **Full**

3.Click **Add** and specify the location and backup name

[image]

4.Copy the created backup file to another computer

5.In SQL Server Management Studio on another computer, right-click the SQL Server instance and select **Restore Database**

[image]

6.Select **Device** and click the elipsis button to navigate to the copied backup file

[image]

Comment: correct answer, but the bak file is huge (more than 30GB).. and I get an error, and cant store it on the computer, (I assume that a lot of people encountered this issue._

There is a way to reduce the file or some other way?

Comment: @RoeiGrinshpan : I don't see how the Restore can be done in a different PC without a connection of some sort or some form of RDP, SFTP, etc. Just how do you enter in "Restore to', the path to in a different PC?

Answer (score 1):

Use TSQL backup and restore. This should help http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/use-t-sql-to-back-up-and-restore-sql-server-user-databases

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do this is back up and restore.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx

Another option you have is detaching your database from SQL Server, copying the MDF and LDF files to the target machine, and re-attaching there.  Note, if you want to keep a copy of the database on the original server, you will also need to attach there too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the content of your database and restore it on another machine. The same mechanism can be used also for backup purposes. Check the backup&restore functionality of MS SQL.