# How to allow others to run Web App using LocalDb

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, localdb

I have created this assignment where I am essentially using .net Core to read and write to an instance of a SQL localDb: [Github](https://github.com/Jacob0421/Bartender-App.git)

This is my first time using a localdb, but when I submitted it to my professor, he is not able to create, or manipulate the database at all. My thoughts were that when he runs it, it would create and instance of the database on his computer, but I guess not. He gets the following error:

**SqlException: Cannot open database 'Bartender_App' requested by login. The Login failed. Login failed for user "Username"**

this error occurs when trying to create a new order. Is there any way to bypass this authentication? because the web app works on my computer.

would he have to create his own migrations and update the database from Visual Studios on his end?

I have tried to look it up, but come across deployment of these web apps to a server which is not what I am trying to do, I am just aiming for him to be able to run the application on his computer, even if the database starts empty, and he can manipulate, add, and remove the data from the localDb instance

I apologize in advance for the tags - the autocomplete feature was not showing up correctly.

Comment: Hi,did my answer help you solve your problem? If it is solved, please accept it as the answer, otherwise, please tell me your still existing problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to bypass this authentication? because the web app
> works on my computer.

**This is impossible, SQL Server Express LocalDB does not accept remote connections.**

As an alternative,  you can automate the backup of your database structure and provide it to your instructor, you can refer to [How to copy a database from one computer to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8715739/12884742).

If there is not much table, manual creation may be faster and easier.

More details ,have a look for [Can SQL Server Express LocalDB be connected to remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9217207/12884742).